# Remove Multiple Items from Array using underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this:

```
var arrA = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}];
```

I have another array:

```
var arrB = [{id:1,other:'c'},{id:3,other:'d'}];
```

How can I remove the items from arrA that have property id same as arrB using underscore.js?

The expected result should be:

```
arrA = [{id:2, name:'b'}];
```

Thanks,

Comment: Must be used underscoreJS?

Comment: javascript would be too messy. or you have any other libraries? lodash would be fine too.

Comment: I have only javascript solution

Comment: ok, lets post a plunkr or jsfiddle in the comment here. don't post the answer, might get downvote because that's not answering the question. thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Here is the link. Check the browser console to see the result

https://jsfiddle.net/y9tsee7g/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
var output = arrA.filter((el) => {
  return arrB.findIndex((elem) => {
    return elem.id == el.id;
  }) == -1;
});
```

**One liner:**

```
arrA.filter((el) => (arrB.findIndex((elem) => (elem.id == el.id)) == -1));
```

---

```js
var arrA = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'a'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'b'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'c'
}];


var arrB = [{
  id: 1,
  other: 'c'
}, {
  id: 3,
  other: 'd'
}];

var op = arrA.filter(function(el) {
  return arrB.findIndex(function(elem) {
    return elem.id == el.id;
  }) == -1;
});
console.log(op);
```

**Or** using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var arrA = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'a'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'b'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'c'
}];


var arrB = [{
  id: 1,
  other: 'c'
}, {
  id: 3,
  other: 'd'
}];

var op = arrA.filter(function(el) {
  return !arrB.find(function(elem) {
    return elem.id == el.id;
  });
});
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
var arrA = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}];
var arrB = [{id:1,other:'c'},{id:3,other:'d'}];
var keys = _.keys(_.indexBy(arrB, "id"));
var result = _.filter(arrA, function(v) {
   return !_.contains(keys, v.id.toString());
});
console.log(result)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript you can use `forEach()` loop and `splice()` to remove object if it's `id` is found in other array.

```js
var arrA = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}];
var arrB = [{id:1,other:'c'},{id:3,other:'d'}];

var b = arrB.map(e => e.id);

arrA.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if(b.indexOf(e.id) != -1) arrA.splice(i, 1);
});

console.log(arrA);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arrA = [{id:1,name:'a'}, {id:2,name:'b'}, {id:3,name:'c'}];
var arrB = [{id:1,other:'c'}, {id:3,other:'d'}];

var res = arrB.reduce((acc, b) => {
  return acc.filter(({id}) => id !== b.id);
}, arrA);

// [{id:2,name:'b'}]
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the difference, but unfortunately that won't work for objects. Instead you could try this:

```
arrA = _.filter(arrA, function(obj){
           return !_.findWhere(arrB, {id: obj.id});
       });
```

You could do this without underscore using the build in *filter* and *find* functions.